# How to find address of function pointers in a running process?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, find, memory-address

How to find address of function pointers in a running process?

I am currently using C++ under Windows XP and wish to find the address of a function. Could somebody help me please? If you could, please give me an example. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way: Use the debug symbols.

If there are no symbols, you're going to have to figure out where your functions are the hard way (reverse compile, find entry points, find function which looks like the one you want). Software such as IDA Pro is your best bet.

Comment: Adding to this, the function may not even have an address; it might be inlined. OTOH, if it's an API function we're talking about then you can inject a GetProcAddress call into the process.